# Silverlight event delegates

Tags: silverlight, events, canvas, grid, mouse

I am dynamically building an org chart in Silverlight 2 by adding lots of Grid containers to a canvas.  Each grid container represents a node within the chart.  I am capturing click events for the nodes as follows:

```
grid.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(grid_MouseLeftButtonUp);
```

By design, each click event changes the look of the tree, so on capturing a click event I rebuild the entire org tree.
This works ok for two or three clicks, but after that everything just hangs when I click a node (Grid).  Each time I rebuild the tree I clear the base canvas using:

```
_canvasBase.Children.Clear();
```

I am wondering if I need to specifically clear all the event delegates before clearing all the canvas children?  Or might something else be happening to cause the hang?

Comment: Check out this post: [LeakEvent → WeakEvent](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2012/02/01/weak-event-handler-for-silverlight.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will be leak memory badly if you do not remove the event handlers.

Comment: Thanks - can you advise on the best way to remove all subscribed handlers for a particular uielement?  In the code I will not actually know which handlers are linked up to each element.